# Rails 4 - Switching from SQLite to MySQL - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, innodb, myisam

To make a long story short, I started writing an app that wasn't going to make it to production, but my boss liked it and asked me to deploy it. Now I have to make the switch from SQLite to MySQL to get the app on the production server.

I added the gem: `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'`, did a `bundle install`, and updated database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: umc2_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: umc2_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: umc2
  username: umc2
  password: <%= ENV['PRODUCTION_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

The migrations aren't doing anything complicated. The all look something like this:

```
create_table :checkins do |t|
  t.string :public_ip
  t.string :private_ip
  t.string :ubermix_version
  t.string :kernel
  t.string :architecture
  t.integer :battery_capacity
  t.integer :system_free
  t.integer :home_free
  t.integer :user_free
  t.references :device, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.references :location, index: true, foreign_key: true

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

When I migrate the database, the console spits this out:

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't create table 'umc2.#sql-4e7_10' (errno: 150): \
ALTER TABLE `checkins` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_ba93b88497`
```

I've been banging my head on this one for a few hours. Am I missing something? Have I inadvertently introduced a some sort of storage engine problem? MySQL 5.7.10 should default to InnoDB, right?

Comment: The 150 error is generally due to a data type mismatch between the parent and referencing columns. They must be exactly the same, and further, the parent column must have _some_ index on it - it may be a primary key, or if not, it must be indexed.  Post the MySQL output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE checkins` and also for the table it references so we can see what has been indexed.  (it could also be due to the parent table not yet existing when you try to create the referencing table)

Comment: This is the first migration that runs, so it looks like I need to go through and rework/reorder them. I guess SQLite doesn't complain if they get created out of order.

Comment: Yes - the order will definitely be important. There may be other indexing issues later.

Comment: It complains about the production DB ('umc2.#sql-4e7_10'). Comment out production and make migration work in development and test. Then focus on production DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was running SQLite I used the resource generator like this: `rails g resource checkin device:references`. When you pass in the `references` type to the generator, it automatically appends `index: true, foreign_key: true` to the appropriate line in the migration file. The parent table has to exist before you can create a reference table with MySQL, but SQLite doesn't complain if the parent table doesn't exist first.

I had to write additional migrations that added the reference columns to the checkins table. I think you can remove the `foreign_key: true` bit and not affect the ActiveRecord relationships, but I'm not sure if that's the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

I case of `MySql error: 150`, the below conditions must be satisfied.

1. The two tables must have the same engine i.e. ENGINE=InnoDB, ENGINE=MyISAM, etc.
2. The two tables must have the same charset.
3. The `Primary Key` column(s) in the parent table and the `Foreign Key` column(s) in the child table must be the same data type.
4. `Primary Key` column(s) in the parent table and the `Foreign Key` column(s) in the child table, if they have a define collation type, must have the same collation
   type.
5. If there is data already in the `Foreign Key` table, the `Foreign Key` column value(s) must match values in the `Primary Key` table `Primary Key` columns.
6. And the child table cannot be a temporary table.

Hope this would be helpful.